# Android Media Player (set dataSource Failed)

Tags: android, xml, android-mediaplayer, listactivity

Hi so im starting off with a basic music app, dont be hating on me for not using recyclerview. But the app runs just fine and no force closes however when I click on a song the song wont play. The android moniter says "
Music App Test 1: setDataSource failed"
Im not sure if my problem is related to my directory or not so let me know.
Also let me know if you need to see the xml files.

```
    package com.example.abhishek.musicapptest1;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnHoverListener;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Mp3filter implements FilenameFilter {// filters all files that are mp3

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File directory, String song_name) { // will return mp3
        return (song_name.endsWith(".mp3"));
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String SD_PATH = new String("/sdcard/Music/Phone Music");

    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();
    private MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        updatePlaylist();

        Button stopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopBtn);
        stopPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
            }

        });


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position, long id) {
        try {
            mp.reset();
            mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.v(getString(R.string.app_name),e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void updatePlaylist() {// will update the play list, will find the sd card
        // we need to filter out the files which we dont want

        File home = new File(SD_PATH);
        if (home.listFiles(new Mp3filter()).length > 0) {
            for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3filter())) {
                songs.add(file.getName());
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.song_view, songs);
            setListAdapter(songList);

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.abhishek.musicapptest1/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.example.abhishek.musicapptest1/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your code, check these lines:

```
private static final String SD_PATH = new String("/sdcard/Music/Phone Music");
songs.add(file.getName());
mp.setDataSource(SD_PATH + songs.get(position));
```

Therefore your DataSource is not a valid filename, a backslash is missing.